# Difference between "devoir" and "falloir"

Tags: subjonctif, verbes-modaux

How do you say "The dishes need to be washed":

> Les assiettes doivent être lavées.

or

> Les assiettes faille être lavées.

Answer (score 6):

### The correct subjonctive

There are 2 problems with your subjonctive try:
1. There must be a "que"
2. It is very odd to use "faire" here on the passive form

The correct subjonctive form would be :

> Qu'il faille laver les assiettes

---

### Use of "falloir" to mean "need to"

"Il faut que + subjonctif" means "need to", so the correct sentence would be:

> Il faut que les assiettes soient lavées

---

### Difference between "falloir" and "devoir"

So here you have 2 ways to say the same thing :

> Il faut que les assiettes soient lavées
>   Les assiettes doivent être lavées

The difference is very small, I think you can use one or the other in any context, without being misunderstood.
The first one slightly emphasizes the result (to be cleaned), and the second one slightly emphasizes the action (to clean).

Comment: La différence est assez subtile effectivement. Je ne connaissais pas les considérations résultat vs action. Généralement, *il faut* insiste sur la nécessité alors que *devoir* exprime souvent une obligation.

Answer (score 0):

Seul *les assiettes doivent être lavées* est correct.

Faille est le subjonctif du verbe [falloir](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/falloir), qui s'emploie à la forme impersonnel (3ème du singulier).

Si on veut l'employer il faut dire : *il faut laver les assiettes.*